# Using pandas how to use column data field for random sample

Tags: python, pandas, sample

I know how to randomly sample few rows from a pandas data frame.

using sample command

```
df_sample = df.sample(n=10)
```

However what I need is random column(i.e Village)  from the below data frame.

[image: Dummy Data:]

For example : I want to randomly select 3 Villages entire data, i.e Village A, B & C. Village A,B & C will be randomly selected and give us output for entire data for this 3 villages.

likewise,

[image]

Here is my code

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df=pd.read_excel("/home/Study.xlsx")
>>> df=df.sample(n=3)
>>> df
    Sr.No  ...  Village
16     17  ...        I
33     34  ...        Q
36     37  ...        S
```

So, I need that, if village I , Q and S are randomly selected, than i required entire data for this 3 villages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with unique values for random 3 villages and then filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
vil = np.random.choice(df['Village'].unique(), 3)
df = df[df['Village'].isin(vil)]
```

Pandas only solution with [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html):

```
vil = df['Village'].drop_duplicates().sample(3)
df = df[df['Village'].isin(vil)]
```

For functions use:

```
def random_vil(x):
    vil = np.random.choice(df['Village'].unique(), x)
    return df[df['Village'].isin(vil)]

 df = random_vil(3)
```

Comment: thank you, can you please help me out how to write this in a function def f(x)  how to write this?